# How do I make a dataframe in python, using different series?

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-science, series

I am trying to make a dataframe using two arrays that are listing average values. The other two sets of values I would like to incorporate are extracted from another dataset.

This is what I have tried:

```
column_a = data_set['column_1']
column_b = data_set['column_2']
df = pd.DataFrame([column_a, column_b, average_1, average_2])
print(df)
```

The output was strangely formatted:

```
                                     0            1            2   
column_a                  North Europe  East Europe  West Europe   
average_1                          143      100.755        175.1   
average_2                        297.9       171.21       227.55   
column_b                        79.265      60.8078       76.468
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with what you have now? Is it as simple as `df=df.T` to transpose the dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'column_a' : ['North Europe','East Europe','West Europe'],  
    'average_1' : [143, 100.755, 175.1],  
    'average_2' : [297.9, 171.21, 227.55 ],                   
    'column_b' : [79.265, 60.8078, 76.468],                                                                         
    })

data_set = pd.DataFrame(d)

column_a = data_set['column_a']
column_b = data_set['column_b']
average_1 = data_set['average_1']
average_2 = data_set['average_2']

df = pd.DataFrame([column_a, column_b, average_1, average_2])

df = df.T
print(df)

       column_a column_b average_1 average_2
0  North Europe   79.265       143     297.9
1   East Europe  60.8078   100.755    171.21
2   West Europe   76.468     175.1    227.55
```

Or you can use `pd.concat` instead:

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'column_a' : ['North Europe','East Europe','West Europe'],                    
    'column_b' : [79.265, 60.8078, 76.468],                                                                         
     })

data_set1 = pd.DataFrame(d)

d = ({  
    'average_1' : [143, 100.755, 175.1],  
    'average_2' : [297.9, 171.21, 227.55],                                                                                          
     })

data_set2 = pd.DataFrame(d)

column_a = data_set1['column_a']
column_b = data_set1['column_b']
average_1 = data_set2['average_1']
average_2 = data_set2['average_2']

df = pd.concat([column_a, column_b, average_1, average_2], axis = 1)

print(df)

       column_a column_b average_1 average_2
0  North Europe   79.265       143     297.9
1   East Europe  60.8078   100.755    171.21
2   West Europe   76.468     175.1    227.55
```